# .click() function is not letting the control enter the function body

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance

I have been given an assignment (Hot or Cold) with HTML/CSS files provided and I have to write and implement the required functions using JQuery, but the. there is a form that Takes input from user via `<input/>` and then another `<input/>`

is used as a button to submit that input from user. Now the problem is the the control enters the body of function if and only if the button is pressed with  field empty otherwise it simply leaves the function.

The code contains 4 functions in total:

1. Instructions (Working Fine)
2. Hide Instructions (Working Fine)
3. Start a New Game (Working Fine)
4. Make a Guess (Problematic)

The function should do the following:

1. Generate a random number from 1 to 100.
2. Take an input from user as an integer from 1 to 100.
3. Compare the user input if guessed right or not.
4. Append the wrong guess to `<ul>` as a separate `<li>`(sharing this part)

   ```
   $('.button').click(function(){
       var currentGuess = $("js-user-guess").val();
       if(currentGuess != "" && currentGuess  >= '0' && currentGuess <='100')
       {
           $('.js-guess-list').append('<li>'+currentGuess+'</li>');
       }
   });
   ```

The expected result is if the input is validated by 'if' it should append to `<ul>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what result you're getting but you definitely have a problem in this part:

```
if(currentGuess != "" && currentGuess  >= '0' && currentGuess <='100')
```

Your conditional compares the guess to the strings `'0'` and `'100'`. Javascript will probably try to compare these alphabetically or something. You should be comparing them to the numbers `0` and `100`.

Also `currentGuess` may be a string, so you may need to `parseInt()` it.

Try changing that line to say this:

```
if(currentGuess != "" && parseInt(currentGuess,10)  >= 0 && parseInt(currentGuess,10) <= 100);
```

Comment: Thankyou for your help @jimboweb using `js-user-guess").val();`was generating an 'undefined' on console so I tried `js-user-guess").text();` and it generated a string as you told in your answer. I just then tried `parseInt()` to convert it into number but I found out that the string I got was nothing but a blank. I then replaced the `<input type="submit" class="button"\>` to `<button>` and it started working fine. Can you explain what was wrong in using `<input\>`?

Comment: `<input type = 'submit'>` doesn't have text in it because it's a singleton tag, while a `<button></button>` is a pair tag so it has text inside it. The `value` attribute of a  submit input is something you'd set as an attribute in the tag, as in `<input type = 'submit' value = '10'>`. If you had that I'm not sure why it wasn't being returned in the js.

Comment: But whatever the case is, the Value is being taken from another `<input>` the problem is fixed but still I have confusion in mind, here's the code working fine `<form>
    <input name="user-guess" id="js-user-guess" class="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Enter a number between 0 and 100" required/>
         <button type="submit" id="js-guess-submit" class="button">Submit Answer</button>
   </form>` changing the `<button>` to `<input\>` causes it to submit blank.

Comment: I don't know why that happens. I don't understand the role the backslash (`<input\>`) is supposed to take in your code. I thought it was a typo before but you keep using it, so it seems you intend it to be in there. If you're trying to end a singleton tag (like you would `<br />` you want a forward slash. I don't know what that would do, so maybe that's the problem?

Comment: It could also be because `<input type = "submit">` by default sends you to a new page with an http request. This is a fairly outdated behavior, based on the way forms worked before REST came to dominate web applications. You can usually prevent this behavior if your click event has an `event` argument and ends with `event.preventDefault()`. But honestly I don't know why this is happening. I'd say if using `<button>` solves the problem, then use `<button>` unless you have a good reason not to. `<button>` is a better tag for this anyway, since you're not redirecting to a new page.

Comment: I'm already using `event.preventDefault()`, actually I was told not to modify `HTML` document and write JavaScript only. Anyways you helped a lot by introducing `parseInt()` , Thanks again.